# Book (possibly Russian?) in which humans had their heads transformed into metallic balls

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify a pre-1989 science fiction novel I read in Romania. Because of the political situation in that time, I think it likely it was written by a Russian author but I don't know this for certain.

All I remember from the novel is that there was a plague which affected humans by transforming their heads into "metallic?" balls. I could have been the effect of some alien transmission, but I don't remember much

Also for the Romanian users here on stackexchange, I think that the cover was yellow and the format was small.

Comment: Not muich to go on. Do yo remember anything else? How about what was the effect of the change on the affected people? Could they no longer hear, see, talk, think? Did they know they were transformed at all, etc?

Comment: I remember that the people who were affected actually died. Their head was transforming into a ball (think of a morphing effect, that's what I imagined then). I also think the transformation was due to some alien message being received by the humans (or at least some kind of message).

Comment: The metal-head sounds like Algis Budrys' [*Who?*](http://www.amazon.com/Who-Algis-Budrys/dp/158776010X) , but that wasn't any kind of plague but the result of an accident.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It's close, but it is not it. There were more than one person affected by the disease and they all died.

Comment: I vaguely remember a short story similar to this, but it definitely wasn't a novel that I read.

Comment: I really don't remember the length of the book. It could have been a short story... Can you give me some details?

Answer (score 4):

Could be that you refer to the story "White Cane 7.62" by Ondřej Neff (Czech writer).  Story is a bit similar (although in that book humans were not dying but turning into aliens).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ond%C5%99ej_Neff

I chould not find the English translation, only Russian one:

http://www.lib.ru/SOCFANT/NEFF/trost.txt

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out. I have a friend who speaks Russian and he'll help me translate. Google Translate didn't do a good job so far.